# Removing duplicate words in a string in R

Tags: r, duplicates

Just to help someone who's just voluntarily removed their question, following a request for code he tried and other comments. Let's assume they tried something like this:

```r
str <- "How do I best try and try and try and find a way to to improve this code?"
d <- unlist(strsplit(str, split=" "))
paste(d[-which(duplicated(d))], collapse = ' ')
```

and wanted to learn a better way. So what is the best way to remove a duplicate word from the string?

Comment: That seems like a good solution, although you may want to `gsub` out the punctuation, otherwise e.g. "code?" in the example sentence would not be marked a duplicate of an earlier standalone "code".

Answer (score 12):

If you are still interested in alternate solutions you can use `unique` which slightly simplifies your code.

```
paste(unique(d), collapse = ' ')
```

As per the comment by Thomas, you probably do want to remove punctuation.  R's `gsub` has some nice internal patterns you can use instead of strict regex.  Of course you can always specify specific instances if you want to do some more refined regex.

```
d <- gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", d)
```

Answer (score 8):

There are no need additional package

```
str <- c("How do I best try and try and try and find a way to to improve this code?",
         "And and here's a second one one and not a third One.")
```

Atomic function:

```
rem_dup.one <- function(x){
  paste(unique(tolower(trimws(unlist(strsplit(x,split="(?!')[ [:punct:]]",fixed=F,perl=T))))),collapse = " ")
}
rem_dup.one("And and here's a second one one and not a third One.")
```

Vectorize

```
rem_dup.vector <- Vectorize(rem_dup.one,USE.NAMES = F)
rem_dup.vector(str)
```

REsult

```
"how do i best try and find a way to improve this code" "and here's a second one not third"
```

Answer (score 6):

To remove duplicate words except for any special characters. use this function

```
rem_dup_word <- function(x){
x <- tolower(x)
paste(unique(trimws(unlist(strsplit(x,split=" ",fixed=F,perl=T)))),collapse = 
" ")
}
```

Input data:

```
duptest <- "Samsung WA80E5LEC samsung Top Loading with Diamond Drum, 6 kg 
(Silver)"

rem_dup_word(duptest)
```

output: `samsung wa80e5lec top loading with diamond drum 6 kg (silver)`

It will treat "Samsung" and "SAMSUNG" as duplicate

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if string case is a concern.  This solution uses `qdap` with the add-on `qdapRegex` package to make sure that punctuation and beginning string case doesn't interfere with the removal but is maintained:

```
str <- c("How do I best try and try and try and find a way to to improve this code?",
    "And and here's a second one one and not a third One.")

library(qdap)
library(dplyr) # so that pipe function (%>% can work) 

str %>% 
    tolower() %>%
    word_split() %>% 
    sapply(., function(x) unbag(unique(x))) %>% 
    rm_white_endmark() %>%  
    rm_default(pattern="(^[a-z]{1})", replacement = "\\U\\1") %>%
    unname()

## [1] "How do i best try and find a way to improve this code?"
## [2] "And here's a second one not third."
```

Comment: what is word_split() function, when tried to run this code, it threw error on word_split().

Comment: Did you install the **qdap** package?

Comment: !Ahh. I got it. I didn't notice that i have problen with rJava package which is a kind of dependency for qdap. Thanks @Rinker.