# keep only unique elements in string in r

Tags: r, string, unique

In genomics research, you often have many strings with duplicate gene names. I would like to find an efficient way to only keep the unique gene names in a string. This is an example that works. But, isn't it possible to do this in one step, i.e., without having to split the entire string and then having to past the unique elements back together?

```
genes <- c("GSTP1;GSTP1;APC")
a <- unlist(strsplit(genes, ";"))
paste(unique(a), collapse=";")
[1] "GSTP1;APC"
```

Comment: This just combines it into one line: `paste(unique(unlist(strsplit(genes, ";")),collapse=";")) `.

Comment: I have seen this one on stack: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20283624/removing-duplicate-words-in-a-string-in-r

Comment: I will be really surprised if you"ll find anything better. Except maybe adding `fixed = TRUE` to `strsplit` for efficiency gain. There is also `stringi::stri_unique` that claims to be more suited for NLP than `base::unique` (but much slower too).

Comment: You can write yourself a function that does these two pieces...

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is doing

```
unique(unlist(strsplit(genes, ";")))
#[1] "GSTP1" "APC"
```

Then this should give you the answer

```
paste(unique(unlist(strsplit(genes, ";"))), collapse = ";")
#[1] "GSTP1;APC"
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to keep the unique gene names in the same string, seperated by ';'.

Comment: @milan look at updated version , it gives you the exact output you like

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example showed, perhaps

```
gsub("(\\w+);\\1", "\\1", genes)
#[1] "GSTP1;APC"
```

Comment: Thanks. It does work for this example, but it won't work if you have a slightly different string: c("A", "B", "A").