# Removing Duplicate Words Among Multiple Strings Across a Single Vector in R

Tags: r, text, nlp, duplicates

I have a vector made up of multiple strings (in R):

```
vec <- c("the cat the cat ran up the tree tree", "the dog ran up the up the tree", 
         "the squirrel squirrel ran up the tree")
```

I need clean the duplicate words from each separate string.

Desired output:

```
"the cat ran up the tree"
"the dog ran up the tree"
"the squirrel ran up the tree"
```

I've tried the solution under: [Removing duplicate words in a string in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20283624/removing-duplicate-words-in-a-string-in-r) . However this only conglomerates my multiple strings into a single complex string.

Comment: I would like to up vote this (it is a helpful answer that adds to the knowledge base), but I am unable to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `gsub` to match two sets of words and one word repeats

```
gsub("((\\w+\\s+\\w+\\s?)|(\\w+\\s+))\\1+", "\\1", vec)
#[1] "the cat ran up the tree"    
#[2]  "the dog ran up the tree"     
#[3] "the squirrel ran up the tree"
```

Comment: Can you recommend a regex tutorial that covers these rules?

Comment: @EnglishmanBob Perhaps [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/34039/regex-to-remove-repeating-words-in-a-sentence) would give some similar syntax explanation