# Possible in R? Combining multiple texts (a) for each member of the group and (b) by the group

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyr

I would like to ask for your help with aggregating texts by group (dyad_id) ***and*** for each member. For each dyad, alter and ego took turns (sometimes they did not take turns, such as the third observation of dyad 111_222, where 222 initiated a new discussion).

***I'm trying to combine all of the writings (with a space between each message) of each person within a focal dyad.***

**A sample data:**

```
structure(list(dyad_id = c("111_222 ", "111_222 ", "111_222 ", 
"333_111 ", "333_111 "), alter = c(111, 222, 222, 333, 111), 
    ego = c(222, 111, 111, 111, 333), message_original = c("Hello my idea is this         ", 
    "I agree with your point       ", "In this essay I would like to ", 
    "I think he should not         ", "Can you tell me more          "
    ), message_ego_response = c("I agree with your point       ", 
    "Same here                     ", "That's a great idea           ", 
    "Can you tell me more          ", "Yes to elaborate              "
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L), variable.labels = structure(character(0), names = character(0)), codepage = 65001L)
```

****The above sample looks like:****

```
+---------+-------+-----+-------------------------------+-------------------------+
| dyad_id | alter | ego |        message_original       |   message_ego_response  |
+---------+-------+-----+-------------------------------+-------------------------+
| 111_222 |  111  | 222 | Hello my idea is this         | I agree with your point |
+---------+-------+-----+-------------------------------+-------------------------+
| 111_222 |  222  | 111 | I agree with your point       | Same here               |
+---------+-------+-----+-------------------------------+-------------------------+
| 111_222 |  222  | 111 | In this essay I would like to | That's a great idea     |
+---------+-------+-----+-------------------------------+-------------------------+
| 333_111 |  333  | 111 | I think he should not         | Can you tell me more    |
+---------+-------+-----+-------------------------------+-------------------------+
| 333_111 |  111  | 333 | Can you tell me more          | Yes to elaborate        |
+---------+-------+-----+-------------------------------+-------------------------+
```

**The output I'm looking for:**

```
+---------+---------+-----------------------+---------+-------------------------------+------------------------------------+
| dyad_id | member1 |   member1's messages  | member2 |       member2's messages      |                Note                |
+---------+---------+-----------------------+---------+-------------------------------+------------------------------------+
| 111_222 |   111   | Hello my idea is this |   222   | I agree with your point       | 222's "I agree with your point" is |
|         |         | Same here             |         | In this essay I would like to | a duplicate (one in 'message_ego'  |
|         |         | That's a great idea   |         |                               | and the other in 'message_alter')  |
+---------+---------+-----------------------+---------+-------------------------------+------------------------------------+
| 333_111 |   333   | I think he should not |   111   | Can you tell me more          | Same here for the duplication      |
|         |         | Yes to elaborate      |         |                               |                                    |
+---------+---------+-----------------------+---------+-------------------------------+------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

1. First `group_by` the `dyad_id` column, then assign `member` by splitting `dyad_id` by "_".
2. Since all of your columns have trailing white spaces, I removed them by `stringr::str_trim()`.
3. Then reorder the messages by the position in `dyad_id` (first two `ifelse()` chunks).
4. After that, check if there's duplicates (the other two `ifelse()` chunks).
5. If either `Note1` or `Note2` is `NA`, `coalesce` them together to replace the `NA`. If both of them are not `NA`, `paste` them together.
6. In the `summarize` part, collapse multiple strings from the same member together.
7. Finally, `relocate` the columns to your desired position.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  group_by(dyad_id) %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~str_trim(.x, "right")),
         dyad_id = gsub(" $", "", dyad_id), 
         member1 = strsplit(dyad_id, "_")[[1]][1],
         member2 = strsplit(dyad_id, "_")[[2]][2],
         member_1_message = ifelse(paste0(alter, "_", ego) == dyad_id, message_original, message_ego_response),
         member_2_message = ifelse(paste0(alter, "_", ego) == dyad_id, message_ego_response, message_original),
         Note1 = ifelse(length(member_1_message[duplicated(member_1_message)]) == 0, 
                        NA, 
                        paste(member1,"'s", member_1_message[duplicated(member_1_message)], "is a duplicate")),
         Note2 = ifelse(length(member_2_message[duplicated(member_2_message)]) == 0, 
                        NA, 
                        paste(member2,"'s", member_2_message[duplicated(member_2_message)], "is a duplicate")),
         Note = ifelse(is.na(Note1) | is.na(Note2), coalesce(Note1, Note2), paste(Note1, Note2, sep = ";"))) %>% 
  summarize(across(starts_with("member"), ~paste0(unique(.x), collapse = " ")),
            Note = unique(Note)) %>% 
  relocate(dyad_id, member1, member_1_message, member2, member_2_message, Note)

# A tibble: 2 × 6
  dyad_id member1 member_1_message                                    member2 member_2_message                                      Note                                   
  <chr>   <chr>   <chr>                                               <chr>   <chr>                                                 <chr>                                  
1 111_222 111     Hello my idea is this Same here That's a great idea 222     I agree with your point In this essay I would like to 222 's I agree with your point is a duplicate
2 333_111 333     I think he should not Yes to elaborate              111     Can you tell me more                                  111 's Can you tell me more is a duplicate
```

Comment: thank you, I just deleted the lines for Note1 and Note2 (which are unnecessary). It works!

Answer (score 0):

Run these steps one by one and note the comments in the code. This will help you understand what the code is doing at each step.

```
library(tidyverse)

# This function is to remove duplicates, source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41280102/11907016
rem_dup.one <- function(x){
  paste(unique(tolower(trimws(unlist(strsplit(x,split="(?!')[ [:punct:]]",fixed=F,perl=T))))),collapse = " ")
}

structure(list(dyad_id = c("111_222 ", "111_222 ", "111_222 ", 
                           "333_111 ", "333_111 "), alter = c(111, 222, 222, 333, 111), 
               ego = c(222, 111, 111, 111, 333), message_original = c("Hello my idea is this         ", 
                                                                      "I agree with your point       ", "In this essay I would like to ", 
                                                                      "I think he should not         ", "Can you tell me more          "
               ), message_ego_response = c("I agree with your point       ", 
                                           "Same here                     ", "That's a great idea           ", 
                                           "Can you tell me more          ", "Yes to elaborate              "
               )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L), variable.labels = structure(character(0), names = character(0)), codepage = 65001L) %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  # Remove white space
  dplyr::mutate_if(is.character,~str_squish(.)) %>% 
  # Combine both messages
  tidyr::unite("message_original and message_ego_response", c(message_original, message_ego_response),sep = "_") %>% 
  # Combine alter and ego
  tidyr::unite("alter_ego",c(alter,ego),sep = "_") %>% 
  # Split into groups so that its easier to handle data and visualise steps at the same time
  dplyr::group_by_all() %>% 
  dplyr::group_split() %>% 
  purrr::map_df(~{
    .x %>% 
      # This entire set of functions will combine the message and the alter_ego code so that its easier to group similar codes together
      tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = !matches("dyad_id"),values_to = "alter_ego_message_original_message_ego_response") %>% 
      tidyr::separate(alter_ego_message_original_message_ego_response,c("alter","ego"),sep = "_",remove = F) %>%
      dplyr::select(-name) %>%
      dplyr::mutate_at(vars(matches("alter|ego")),~str_c(.,collapse = "__")) %>%
      dplyr::slice(1) %>%
      tidyr::separate(alter_ego_message_original_message_ego_response,c("alter_ego","message_original_message_ego_response"),sep = "__")
  }) %>% 
  # in the above steps, the code and messages were combined
  dplyr::group_by(dyad_id) %>% 
  # Now the combination of messages is the next step
  dplyr::group_split() %>% 
  purrr::map_df(~{
    .x %>% 
      dplyr::select(matches("dyad|alter$|^ego")) %>%
      tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = matches("alter$|^ego"),names_to = "alter/ego",values_to = "Code_message") %>% 
      dplyr::select(-`alter/ego`) %>% 
      dplyr::arrange(Code_message) %>% 
      tidyr::separate(Code_message,c("Code","message"),sep = "__") %>% 
      dplyr::group_by(Code) %>% 
      dplyr::mutate(message = str_c(message, collapse = " \n ")) %>% 
      dplyr::slice(1) %>% 
      dplyr::ungroup() %>% 
      dplyr::mutate(member = 1:n() %>% str_c("member",.)) %>% 
      tidyr::unite(Code_message,c(Code, message),sep = "_") %>% 
      tidyr::pivot_wider(id_cols = dyad_id,names_from = member,values_from = Code_message) %>% 
      tidyr::separate(member1,c("member1","member1's message"),sep = "_") %>% 
      tidyr::separate(member2,c("member2","member2's message"),sep = "_")
  }) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(dyad_id) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate_at(vars(matches("message")),~rem_dup.one(.)) %>% 
  dplyr::ungroup()
```

Output:

```
dyad_id member1 `member1's message`                               member2 `member2's message`                                 
  <chr>   <chr>   <chr>                                             <chr>   <chr>                                               
1 111_222 111     "hello my idea is this  same here that's a great" 222     i agree with your point  in this essay would like to
2 333_111 111     "can you tell me more "                           333     i think he should not  yes to elaborate
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use a combination of `data.table` and `tidyverse`. First, I convert to a long format using `data.table`, then we can clean up the empty white space (`trimws`), and we can create a new column to note the information about duplicate statements. Then, I collapse the statements for one person (per dyad) using `str_c`. Then, we can pivot back to the wide format and then clean up the column order and names.

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)

names(df) <- c("dyad_id", "member1", "member2", "message1", "message2")

melt(setDT(df), measure = patterns("^member", "^message"), 
     value.name = c("member", "message")) %>% 
  group_by(dyad_id, member) %>% 
  mutate(message = trimws(message),
         dyad_id = trimws(dyad_id),
         notes = ifelse(duplicated(message), message, NA)) %>% 
  summarize(message = str_c(unique(message),collapse = "  "), notes = max(notes, na.rm = T)) %>% 
  mutate(idx = row_number(),
         notes = ifelse(!is.na(notes), paste0("member", row_number(), " duplicate:", notes), NA)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "idx", values_from = c("message", "member")) %>% 
  summarize(across(everything(), ~max(.x, na.rm = T))) %>% 
  select(dyad_id, member_1, message_1, member_2, message_2, notes) %>% 
  set_names(., c("dyad_id", "member1", "member1's message", "member2", "member2's message", "notes"))
```

Output

```
  dyad_id member1 `member1's message`                                   member2 `member2's message`                                    notes                                    
  <chr>     <dbl> <chr>                                                   <dbl> <chr>                                                  <chr>                                    
1 111_222     111 Hello my idea is this  Same here  That's a great idea     222 I agree with your point  In this essay I would like to member2 duplicate:I agree with your point
2 333_111     111 Can you tell me more                                      333 I think he should not  Yes to elaborate                member1 duplicate:Can you tell me more
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- structure(list(dyad_id = c("111_222 ", "111_222 ", "111_222 ", 
                           "333_111 ", "333_111 "),
               alter = c(111, 222, 222, 333, 111), 
               ego = c(222, 111, 111, 111, 333),
               message_original = c("Hello my idea is this         ", 
                                    "I agree with your point       ",
                                    "In this essay I would like to ",
                                    "I think he should not         ",
                                    "Can you tell me more          "),
               message_ego_response = c("I agree with your point       ",
                                        "Same here                     ",
                                        "That's a great idea           ",
                                        "Can you tell me more          ",
                                        "Yes to elaborate              ")
               ),
          class = "data.frame",
          row.names = c(NA, -5L),
          variable.labels = structure(character(0),
                                      names = character(0)),
          codepage = 65001L)

df %>% 
  separate(dyad_id, sep = "_", into = c("member1", "member2")) %>% 
  mutate(
    member1_messages = if_else(member1 == alter, message_original, message_ego_response),
    member2_messages = if_else(member1 == ego, message_original, "")
  ) %>%
  select(-c(alter, ego, message_original, message_ego_response)) %>% 
  group_by(member1) %>% 
  mutate(
    member1_messages = str_squish(paste(member1_messages, collapse = "")),
    member2_messages = str_squish(paste(member2_messages, collapse = ""))
  ) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  distinct()
#> # A tibble: 2 × 4
#>   member1 member2 member1_messages                              member2_messages
#>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>                                         <chr>           
#> 1 111     "222 "  Hello my idea is this Same here That's a gre… I agree with yo…
#> 2 333     "111 "  I think he should not Yes to elaborate        Can you tell me…
```

Comment: I like your code; it is simple! But I get error messages--for member1_messages = if_else... the error is "invalid factor level, NA generated" and for member2_messages = if_else... the error is "`false` must be a `factor` object, not a character vector".

Comment: Does your original dataframe have `message_original` and `message_ego_response` as factors? Also, does the code in my answer not work for you on the `df` in my answer?